# what is the difference between __repr__ and __str__?

Tags: python, string, repr

```
class A():
    def __init__(self,x):
         self.x = x 
    def __repr__(self):
         return self.x
```

For example, if I have a statement like A("one"), the output is one. 
Therefore, can I assume that **repr** is invoked every time when I create a new instance of the class?

Comment: _"Therefore, can I assume that repr is invoked every time when I create a new instance of the class?"_ > No, it is not.  And I am curious how to come up with this conclusion

Answer (score 2):

**__str__ is used for creating output for end user while __repr__ is mainly used for debugging and development. repr’s goal is to be unambiguous and str’s is to be readable.**

A good exemple

```py
import datetime 
today = datetime.datetime.now() 

# Prints readable format for date-time object 
print str(today) 

# prints the official format of date-time object 
print repr(today)
```

will output

```
2016-02-22 19:32:04.078030
datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 22, 19, 32, 4, 78030)
```